# IBM MQ Resource adaptor on JBoss 6.3 Issue

Tags: java, jboss, ibm-mq

I am trying to use IBM MQ adaptor in JBoss first time (even using JBoss for the first time). We are migrating our application from WebSphere7 to JBoss 6.3. And for that i need to configure same MQ's which we used to use on IBM WebSphere. Hence I have started configuring IBM Resource adaptor. Below is the standalone.xml file configuration.
Below config works fine however I am not able to get **QueueConnectionFactory** with code `(QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup("java:/comp/env/serviceQCF")` as it throws class cast exception (**com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ConnectionFactoryImpl** cannot be cast to javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory).

And when I use `connection-definition class-name="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/serviceQCF" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionClass"`, *JBoss is throwing exception

**javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp/env/serviceQCF** -- service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.env.serviceQCF*

I have tried using **ConnectionFactory** however same result (Name not found exception)

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <transaction-support>LocalTransaction</transaction-support>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:/comp/env/serviceQCF" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionClass">
                        <config-property name="port">
                            1414
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="channel">
                            MQ.CLT.STH.CHL
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="hostName">
                            127.0.0.127
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="transportType">
                            MQ.CLIENT
                        </config-property>
                        <config-property name="queueManager">
                            MQSYKHT0
                        </config-property>
                        <security>
                            <application/>
                        </security>
                        <validation>
                            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
                        </validation>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
```

Do I need to configure something Else? Do i need to add/modify any classpath? If yes where and how?

Currently Not setting any property while getting Context:

context = new InitialContext();

But tried using below ones:

```
    final Properties env = new Properties();  
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");  
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
```

but no luck.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

As Doug pointed out you have to use the ManageQueueConnectionFactoryImpl, but for me that wasn't enough.  I also had to add the below to standalone.xml.  Without it I could not cast the IBM QueueConnectFactoryImpl class to a JMS QueueConnectionFactory, even though that class implemented that interface.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0"/>
```

Comment: Can you specify, How we can declare QM/SSL details  ?

Comment: On JBoss EAP 7.2 it was needed to add the following:  <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>

Answer (score 1):

Several things to note here.  The JMS spec has the domain specific:

```
QueueConnectionFactory
TopicConnectionFactory
```

And the non-domain specific:

```
ConnectionFactory
```

You should have the correct type for your code in your server configuration file.  Note that you can look at the ra.xml file packaged in the META-INF folder in the IBM MQ JCA for the types:

```
com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedTopicConnectionFactoryImpl
com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl
com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl
```

Specifically, for a cast to QueueConnectionFactory, you should be using the ManagedQueueConnectionFactoryImpl.

Please note that the IBM MQ JCA managed objects can not be used in remote clients.  They can only be accessed from the JVM that loads the IBM MQ JCA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define the destination 'java:/comp/env/serviceQCF' before trying to use it with the resource adapter.